# The first and second derivative of a triple integral

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

I need the first and second derivative of a triple integral function, and f(x,y) is a density function and differentiable $$ w(v) = \int\limits_0^v \int\limits_0^s \int\limits_0^{u(x)} f(x,y) dy dx ds   $$ I think that Leibniz Rule will give me the solution, but I am not very familiar about that.  $$ Since \space \space F(x)=\int f(x)dx $$ $$I\space \space assume \space \space F(a,y)-F(b,y)=\int\limits_a^b f(x,y)dx $$ 
So I need w' and w''. Any helps would be appreciated

Comment: You cannot simply take a derivative of a multivariable function. You need to take the partial derivative of the function.

Comment: The function $w$ is of a single variable

Comment: w only depends on v, and f(x,y) is a density function depending on x and y. F(x,y) is simply the distribution over x and y ranges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, that $$\frac{d}{dx} \int_c^x g(y) dy = g(x).$$ Then in your case let's write $$\alpha(s)=\int_0^s \beta(x) dx, \qquad \beta(x) = \int_0^{u(x)}f(x,y)dy.$$ Then $$w(v) = \int_0^v \alpha(s) ds,$$ so by the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus $$w'(v) = \alpha(v)=\int_0^v \int_0^{u(x)} f(x,y) dy dx = \int_0^v \beta(x) dx,$$ so again by the FTC $$w''(v) = \beta(v)=\int_0^{u(v)} f(v,y) dy.$$

You could go further and try to calculate the third derivative: this would be more complicated since now the upper limit is not simply $v$, but a function of $v$, and also your function in the integrand depends on $v$ too. Some use of the Chain Rule would be required.

Comment: thank you, that is so clear